# Subject and text fields of shareActionProvider left blank - android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm trying to add a share button to the actionbar. I created the xml file correctly, and this is the code: An implementation of caesar cipher, that takes an int and a string as input and displays the result in another edittext. I think the problem should be because of the frequent update (appending) of the result edittext. When i press share button , it redirects successfully to the specified destination, but both the subject and text are empty. (tried with google keep). Notice I am using shareSubject and shareText strings in the onCreateOptionsMenu method.

```
public class EncrActivity extends Activity {

Button ok, next;
EditText etKey, text, res;
String input, result = "";
int key;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.encr_activity);

    ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bOk);
    next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bNext);
    etKey = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etKey);
    text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etText);
    res = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etResult);

    ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {               

            if (etKey.getText().length() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "please enter a valid value for a",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                key = Integer.parseInt(etKey.getText().toString());
            }

            encrypt(key);
        }
    });
    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {               

            if (etKey.getText().length() == 0) {
                key = 0;
            } else {
                key = Integer.parseInt(etKey.getText().toString());
            }

            key++;              
            etKey.setText(""+key);
            encrypt(key);
        }
    });
}

public boolean isAlpha(int x) {
    if ((x >= 65 && x <= 90) || (x >= 97 && x <= 122)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public void encrypt(int shift){
    res.setText("");

    if (text.getText().length() == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "please don't leave the input empty",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        input = text.getText().toString();
    }

    int length = input.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        int y = input.charAt(i);
        if (isAlpha(y)) {
            if (Character.isUpperCase(y)) {
                int character = (((y - 65) + shift) % 26) + 65;
                char charac = (char) character;
                res.append(charac + "");
            } else if (Character.isLowerCase(y)) {
                int character = (((y - 97) + shift) % 26) + 97;
                char charac = (char) character;
                res.append(charac + "");
            }
        } else {
            res.append(input.charAt(i) + "");
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {     
    String shareSubject = EncrActivity.this.etKey.getText().toString();
    String shareText = EncrActivity.this.res.getText().toString();
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.action_bar_share_menu, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);
    ShareActionProvider myShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) item.getActionProvider();
    Intent myIntent = new Intent();
    myIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    myIntent.setType("text/plain");
    myIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, shareSubject);
    myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareText);        
    myShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(myIntent);
    return true;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the menu (and hence, the share intent) is being created *as soon as the activity is loaded*. At that point the EditText is still empty.

You should instead:

- Store a reference to the `ShareActionProvider` in `onCreateOptionsMenu()`.
- When you call `encrypt()`, create a new Intent and call `setShareIntent()`.

That way the share Intent will be up to date when the share action is executed.

Comment: thanks for the answer, btw is there any similiar example on stackoverflow or anywhere else in the internet, as i'm a bit confused  (newbie)

Comment: @user3810325 See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ShareActionProvider.html It's basically the same pattern: keep reference, then fill intent later.